# T-SQL SELECT из двух таблиц

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы - одна с именами девушек и ребятами которые им нравятся
и таблица с именами парней и девушками которые им нравятся.
Как написать запрос чтобы вывести имена всех девушек которые не нравятся ни одному парню ?

[image: Вид таблиц]

Comment: `select distinct name from girls where name not in (select likes from boys)` ?

Comment: @teran, ответы в ответы?

Answer (score 3):

С использованием left join:

```
SELECT Girls.* FROM Girls
LEFT JOIN Boys ON Girls.Name = Boys.Likes
WHERE Boys.Name IS NULL
```

С использованием EXISTS:

```
SELECT * FROM Girls g
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM Boys b WHERE g.Name = b.Likes)
```